# Google OneClick Technology

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, oneclick

I am trying to make my ClickOnce application work cross-browser. I researched Google Chrome's installer (which behaves like a ClickOnce application BUT works on Chrome, Firefox on Opera) and it seems like google is using something called OneClick (from a script called gu_util.js) - is this proprietary Google technology?

Can I use it somehow for my application?

Answer (score 3):

ClickOnce is not a Google Technology it's a microsoft technology (allow to launch exe on your machine)

[How can Google Chrome be installed directly on webpage without ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315906/how-can-google-chrome-be-installed-directly-on-webpage-without-activex)

> Chrome uses google's project omaha, which is an system that uses clickonce to bootstrap a generic installer engine. That installer is then used to install chrome (they also use it for Google Earth).

If you want to use omaha in your app, the source is available under the Apache License 2.

Hope that's help