# How can Google Chrome be installed directly on webpage without ActiveX

Tags: windows, google-chrome, installation

Does it have a magic?
When I click download button on the webpage, then Google Chrome is downloaded and installed.
It doesn't use ActiveX. And it doesn't even require UAC window in the Vista or later.
How can it be possible?

Please let me know how to make this.
I'd like to make my programs like this.

Comment: It's okay, Google said they aren't evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome uses google's [project omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/), which is an system that uses clickonce to bootstrap a generic installer engine.  That installer is then used to install chrome (they also use it for Google Earth).

If you want to use omaha in your app, the source is available under the [Apache License 2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Answer (score 4):

It uses ClickOnce deployment. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Is it Visual C++ deployment?

Comment: Possibly, but ClickOnce can be used for any executable that does not require permanent installation in Program Files. It's just a system of manifests that describe file locations, required permissions, and publisher identity. VS has built in support for ClickOnce apps but it can be used standalone as well.

Answer (score 2):

UAC isn't involved as the installer does not require elevation; it doesnt use any folders/registry keys that the current user does not already have read/write permissions on.   For example mine is installed in `C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` not `Program Files`.

If you get a seamless download, you probably have the googleupdate service running.